# SQL Server - Index efficiency for group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

Attempting to make indexes that are most efficient for this setup:

```
;WITH CTE AS      
(      
    SELECT 
       CHINFO.CHILDID, CHINFO.CONSUMERID,       
       DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, CHINFO.Adddate)-1), CHINFO.Adddate) AS APPLICATIONUSAGESTARTDATE,      
       DATEDIFF(WW,CHINFO.Adddate,@now) AS WEEKNUMBER,      
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHINFO.CHILDID ORDER BY CHINFO.Adddate ASC) AS RN      
   FROM 
      BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO       
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  
      BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID
   GROUP BY 
      CHINFO.CHILDID, CHINFO.CONSUMERID, CHINFO.Adddate      
) 
SELECT  
   CONSUMERID,      
   CTE.CHILDID,      
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BKA.CHILDEVENTS WHERE TYPE ='POTTYBREAK') AS AGGREGATEDPOTTYBREAKEVENTS,      
   APPLICATIONUSAGESTARTDATE,      
   WEEKNUMBER
FROM 
   CTE
```

I have tried adding a index like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ChildInformation_CHILDID_CONSUMERID_Adddate
    ON BKA.ChildInformation (CHILDID,CONSUMERID,AddDate);
```

In the execution plan am seeing a clustered index scan. How to make it as an index seek? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you doing a group by in the first place? There's no aggregates I can see in your query. And the only part I see that *might* benefit from an index is the `CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID`.

Comment: yes i need a single or distinct childid in the output..if i dont use groupby it ll give same childids in a multiple row as output